# Is there a way to have a GET request with setInterval on the backend without the help of the client side/frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, server-sent-events

I have this GET request that fetches data from a third party api. I want to check if there is new data every 5-10 minutes or so. Right now i have this setup on my backend.

```
exports.get_alerts = async (req, res) => {
  const alertsUrl = `https://www.g2smart.com/g2smart/api/alert?cpo=${req.params.cpo}&status=Opened&limit=10&page=1`;
  const axios = require("axios");
  const auth = await refreshToken;
  const currTime = moment().subtract(1, "days").format("X");
  const newAlertsData = [];

  const availableUsers = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:5000/api/schedule/available"
  ) ....
```

and on the front end i have this code to send a get request to my alerts api endpoint.

```
 getAlerts = async () => {
    axios
      .get("/api/alerts/total_fr_hpc")
      .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  timer = (time) => {
    const date = new Date(time);
    return `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.alertsInterval = setInterval(this.getAlerts, 900000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.alertsInterval);
```

My question is can i have all this done on the backend only? I read a bit about websockets but that seems to be only for a continuous 2way connection between the backend and frontend.

I'd like to have something like that towards my third party apis on the node/express server, either fetching data at a set interval or a continuous connection checking for new data without having to make GET requests from my frontend. I want to be able to get new Data and store it into MongoDB even when there is nobody logged in to the client side.

I want that the data the users get is always up to date without having at least one person logged in to trigger the GET requests.

This is how my node/express server is currently setup

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");


const indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
const apiRouter = require("./routes/api"); //Import routes for "api" area of site

const app = express();

// CORS Middleware

app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
// Bodyparser middleware
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB successfully connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// Routes
// Add api routes to middleware chain.
app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/api", apiRouter);

// Serve static assets (build folder) if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () =>
  console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the axios as I always use the native fetch API. Maybe [the isomorphic fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch) can help.

Comment: fetch and axios do the same thing. That's not my issue. I want to do those requests at setInterval from the backend without having it being triggered from the frontend.

Comment: To use fetch in node instead of browser, use [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch). I would recommend using the [isomorphic unfetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch) when both browser code and node code exists in the same project.